# MCQ questions without exam class in latex

Tags: latex

I want to add a section MCQ question to my ebook with answer key (with explanation) in the last. I dont want to use exam package because i am using book package. The output is like this:

[image: example]

Please anybody advise me or send me template.

Thank you,
Ram

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`tasks` package](//ctan.org/pkg/tasks) for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage{tasks}

\settasks{
  counter-format = {(tsk[a])},
  label-width = 1.5em,
  item-indent = 0pt,
  column-sep = \tabcolsep
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  If $a = 3 + i$ and $z = 2 - 3i$ then the points on the Argand diagram representing $az$, $3az$ and $-az$ are
  \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task Vertices of a right-angled triangle
    \task Vertices of an equilateral triangle
    \task Vertices of an isosceles triangle
    \task Collinear
  \end{tasks}

  \item
  The sum of the numbers $436.32$, $227.2$ and $0.301$ in appropriate significant figures is
  \begin{tasks}(4)
    \task $663.821$
    \task $664$
    \task $663.8$
    \task $663.82$
  \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Please can you u tell me how to print out correct answer key at the end of document section/chapter wise?

Comment: @user6737063: I'd suggest [asking a follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764) on [tex.se].